# IE7 png images loading but appearing with the 'image not found' red x

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, png

Below is an image of the problem.

I've tried correcting the folder permissions to 755, i've tried setting exact paths, i've tried removing all of my styles and nothing works.

Background png images seem to load fine.

There are some flash elements on the page (top and side nav)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: if you right click an image and view properties, what does it show? if you right click and view source, what does it say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there isn't some script applying the png fix for IE6 to IE7 accidentally? In this case it would be inserting an `images/blank.gif` file to make the area "clickable" in certain cases and compensate for lack of png. Though it shouldn't target IE7 since it natively supports it.

You can probably use the Developer Tools or search for any "blank.gif" references in the file(s) you're using and just throw it up there or somehow disable the png fixing thing.

Comment: That appears to have done the trick, thankyou. I'd tried taking the script out before and it didn't work then but now it does. Gotta love IE7!